# Setting Android proxy settings programmatically using System.Global method

Tags: java, android, proxy, settings, android-4.4-kitkat

I am working on an application and I have access to the ROM signature keys.
I want to change Android's global proxy settings programmatically, and bumped upon "Settings.Global.HTTP_PROXY". My application will run on Android KitKat device (4.4+)

Now in my code I have:

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

if (!manager.isWifiEnabled()){
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Wifi not enabled.");
}
else{
    if (Settings.Global.putString(mContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.HTTP_PROXY, proxySettings)){
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "New Proxy Settings set");
    }
    else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "New Proxy Settings failed to be written.");
    }
}
```

And written in the application's manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

As stated before, my application is signed with the System keys so no permission issues. I have set up manually the proxy settings on a WIFI connection to some random values, to test if when the code is executed, the settings would change at all. Logcat would return:

```
08-25 21:27:57.595: V/Provider/Settings(7302): Global.putString(name=http_proxy, value=localhost:8008 for 0
```

meaning that the settings ARE being saved on database, but when I check the proxy settings from the Settings application again, the previously set up proxy settings would still show, and the applications would still use the older proxy settings.

Anything else I am missing here to set global Android proxy settings programmatically?

Thank you!